# How to install OSX app developed with XCode on my own machine?

Tags: xcode, macos, deployment

I am pretty newbie in that subject so any pointers are welcome. I am going to create some UI application for OSX (using Swift language if it's matter). While app in early stages I have no choice other than starting it from XCode, but once app get matured enough to be useful I'd like to install it on my own machine and play with it as regular user would do. Under "install" I mean - it should be visible/accessible in regular way with icons etc.  How to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Just locate the application and drag it to your applications folder

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app bundle (extension .app), you just need to create it using xcode and that's all, here's the documentation with the bundle structure: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

When your app is bundled, move your app to the Applications folder and you're ready to go.